# OkHttp doesn't seem to close connections when the JVM terminates

Tags: jvm, okhttp

In performing some integration tests with OkHttp (4.8.0) against a server that was initially configured to never terminate idle connections, I saw that OkHttp connections were never closed, even when the JVM (the test runner) had terminated.
While I can manually call `evictAll` on the connection pool and that does manually close the socket, I would expect the pool to properly clean up after itself when the JVM exits. Is there some reason that these sockets would be kept open that I'm not thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

For typical client usecases OkHttp shouldn't require an explicit shutdown if you make and consume requests properly.  However normally HTTP/2 works on shared connections (sockets), and these can easily be shared across OkHttpClient instances since you can fork and modify some settings in a new instance.

The threads and sockets should not stop the JVM from terminating, and once the process dies all sockets are closed anyway.  This is considered one form of "clean up".

As you found you can force this if you really want.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/#shutdown-isnt-necessary

Are you wanting an orderly shutdown such that the server knows OkHttp connections are already released, or to help the OS free the sockets?

Comment: While I may be setting up things improperly, it appears to me that "once the process dies all the sockets are closed" isn't as strong a guarantee as I would have thought - it doesn't look like the server is informed that they are closed unless I force-evict them.